# csv.reader, 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, csv

On windows I am using

```
csv.reader(TSV, dialect = "excel-tab")
```

to read a csv file and all works fine. When I try from PyCharm on Mac I get this error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 4767: invalid start byte
```

It looks like 0x93 is the “ quote character. I tried replacing the dialect with

```
csv.reader(TSV, delimiter="\t", quotechar='\x93', doublequote=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

I've also tried other combination of options suggested on the online forums but it never seems to work.

Comment: The first thing I would do is not run it with PyCharm.  The Pycharm environment produces weird bugs sometimes.

Comment: The other thing I would think about is that the encoding might not be utf-8 (since it opens fine on Windows).

Comment: A list of common encodings on windows:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page